# 'Class' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

Here is basic DI pattern:

```
class Foo {
  foo = 1;
}

class Bar {
  constructor(public Foo: typeof Foo) {
    const foo = new Foo();
  }
}

class Baz extends Foo {}
new Bar(Baz);
```

It gives an error:

> 'Foo' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

But it clearly isn't self-referential, because `public Foo` is property name, and `typeof Foo` is type.

What is going on here? Is it TypeScript bug that is expected to be solved in future? Is it documented?

Can `Foo` property name be kept somehow here without renaming it? It just makes sense to name it so.

---

It appears that `public Foo: Foo` doesn't create problems with types, and `Foo` refers to original `Foo` interface in `public AnotherFoo: Foo`:

```
class Bar {
  constructor(public Foo: Foo, public AnotherFoo: Foo) {
    const foo: Foo = AnotherFoo;
    foo.foo;
  }
}
```

And  `typeof Foo` refers to `Foo` parameter type and not original `Foo` interface:

```
class Bar {
  constructor(public Foo: number, Quux: typeof Foo) {
    const quux: number = Quux; 
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you inferring type definition in class declaration? it is redundant. TSlint plugin would give you an exception for redundant definition of type: for example `let variable1: boolean = true` is redundant. For Classes this is an exception because you are referencing to his type and parameter. Just declare a type `_Foo = typeof Foo` and give it to  your class reference - EDIT didn't see answer below. Titian is right

Comment: `type _Foo` is a good workaround. But how comes that type definition is redundant? If I won't specify the type for `public Foo`, it will be `any`. I don't have `public Foo = initialValue` to infer the type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that inside the constructor `Foo` will refer to the parameter not the class, so you can't reference `Foo` by name alone. The simplest way to do it and keep the name of the parameter is to declare a type alias:

```
class Foo {
    foo = 1;
}
type FooType = typeof Foo
class Bar {
    constructor(public Foo: FooType) {
    }
}
```

The reason `Foo : Foo` works but `Foo: typeof Foo` does not work is that after the type `:` a type annotation is expected. If the annotation is a name when searching for the symbol, only types are considered as only they can be valid.

After `typeof` the name of a symbol that has a type  is expected (class, local variable, parameter, etc.). So then the search must include parameters and the `Foo` parameter is in scope so it must be considered.

**Edit**

@artem makes a good point that I did not explicitly call out above:

> [This behavior] is not specific to the constructors. In `typeof Foo`, `Foo` refer to the nearest value (not type) named `Foo` in the scope. Once you have a parameter named `Foo`, it's in the scope (you can even use it as default value to initialize other parameters), and it shadows any outer values named.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the reference or other authoritative that explains this part, *Foo will refer to the parameter not the class*? `public Foo: Foo` works as I initially expected and Foo instance type (not what I need here, but it doesn't cause the error), but ` typeof Foo` serves as the reference to Foo param type, see the update.

Comment: @estus I added an explanation, I am not sure what authoritative source I can provide, I can look for the explanation of how `typeof` works, would that help ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will, if you're referring to [this chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). I suppose that it has something to do with *type queries* rather than with `typeof` in particular. I'm very interested in understanding what exactly is going on in constructor param types. I guess I will offer a bounty if the answer is unable to clear this up. Any way, thanks for the help, FooType is the way it should be done here.

Comment: It's not specific to the constructors. In `typeof Foo`,  Foo refer to the nearest value (not type) named Foo in the scope. Once you have a parameter named Foo, it's in the scope (you can even use it as default value to initialize other parameters), and it shadows any outer values named `Foo`