# Typescript can infer recursive function, but not recursive type

Tags: typescript

Typescript seems to be able to infer the type of a recursive function:

```
/**
 * Typescript correctly infers the type is
 *
 * const referencesSelf: () => ...
 *
 * Where the ellipsis means recursion of the function
 */
const referencesSelf = () => {
  return referencesSelf;
};
```

However, unable to infer a class with a recursive nature:

```
class ReferencesSelf {
  _self: () => ReferencesSelf;

  constructor(gen: () => ReferencesSelf) {
    this._self = gen;
  }
}

/**
 * Typescript warns with:
 *
 * `foo' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is 
 * referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
 */
const foo = new ReferencesSelf(() => {
  return foo;
});
```

Two questions:

1. Why? Is this behavior documented somewhere? I couldn't find any callouts of this.
2. Is there a way to get TS to infer the recursive function type without defaulting to nil?

On Typescript 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question use `as` keyword like that:

```
const foo = new ReferencesSelf(() => {return foo;}) as ReferencesSelf;
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBKBTAZogTogdiRUDKiYysA3sLLAPpSHIBcsAFAJSwC8AfAiuljvrQDcwcrBAB7TFAAuaAK4hp4tIwDmWBi3ZckqDNlwEirMhQrSAFgEsoAOmq12sdZmEUAvsE-AA9ACo-cj9YABUATwAHXBA0KwjpWAB3CDQpJKtLOiCg2AADZHFxAHJYKwBbCLArEAywMNgLaFhpSMRYIohMMJKAI0QQCDkaUoSAE3FcWExxBMaANzaIZtbYTunpCGkrSVXMUdK4HIw9PkR90asMRTrYZVK9y-7pG6tMEbhxRLfXjKsIKoAXuhbNIoIwAOwABgATNDmEEfKBJDJYAVxE5MIhEtwTgYBERGFpOKQMNI5KlUYVBO5WE1dLw8UZkMIgA)

Also see below links. **Maybe** it can help for first part.

[Are circular references supported when using class expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246429/are-circular-references-supported-when-using-class-expressions)

['Class' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640828/class-is-referenced-directly-or-indirectly-in-its-own-type-annotation)

Comment: Hmm, so casts work fine until you want generics:

```
class ReferencesSelf<T> {
  _self: () => T;

  constructor(gen: () => T) {
    this._self = gen;
  }
}

const foo = new ReferencesSelf(() => {return foo;});
```

Any advice? (Or perhaps that's just too convoluted)

Comment: Yes. `as ReferencesSelf<never>;` or as `ReferencesSelf<YourType>;`. [PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQYwNghgzlwEoFMBmCBOCB2IFQMoLCQB4AVAPmAG9gB9KApALmAAoBKYAXgpIG5QA9higAXVAFcQIgahYBzTM3ZceHaiIAWASygA6Ogy7AFGfgF9gFgFDAbWjCLRII2YBEpWbZmzZBDRwEgCAkYYCADu8MhomNh4DEQQZCzK3FToIuKoGIHBvGYc0FEo6Fg4+ISJZLxWQA)

Comment: Not quite - as referencesself cant take itself as a paran